# Behat - format output on long step name

Tags: behat, iterm2

I'm using `behat/mink` calling the `And I should see "A reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally long string` step, and the output is getting formmatted weird because it aligns to that long strong:

```
    And I should see "normal string"                                 # MyName
space\MySubNamespace\MyContext::assertPageContains()
    And I should see "A reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally long string" # MyName
space\MySubNamespace\MyContext::assertPageContains()
```

Is there any option to fix this somehow?

Comment: What console are you using? powershell or bash?

Comment: using oh-my-zshell on iTerm2

Comment: You need to check the terminal default properties and increase window width, also you should increase the screen buffer size on height to make sure all steps are displayed, in case is not displaying all the steps.

Comment: As a conclusion this is not a behat issue.